# python - Loop outputs same timestamp every time

Tags: python, timestamp

I have this code where I reads outputs from other scripts then inputs those in a database. Additionally, a timestamp is added.

```py
    import time
    import os
    import subprocess
    import sys
    from time import sleep
    import datetime
    import sqlite3
    import fnmatch, shutil

    sensorID = "1"
    dbname = 'sensorsData.db'

    t = time.localtime()
    timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', t)


    refresh = 300 #time in seconds , getting new data from sensors

    #get data from sensor
    def gettemp():
        temp = subprocess.check_output("sudo python /home/pi/AIRQMONITOR/temp.py", shell=True)
        print(timestamp)
        return(temp)
    def getpm25():
        pm25 = subprocess.check_output("sudo python /home/pi/AIRQMONITOR/pm2.py", shell=True)
        return (pm25)
    def getpm10():
        pm10 = subprocess.check_output("sudo python /home/pi/AIRQMONITOR/pm10.py", shell=True)
        return (pm10)
    def getco():
        co = subprocess.check_output("sudo python /home/pi/AIRQMONITOR/co.py", shell=True)
        return(co)
#log data
    def logdata(temp,co,pm25,pm10):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
        curs=conn.cursor()
        curs.execute("INSERT INTO sensors values(?,?,?,?,?)", (timestamp, temp, co, pm25, pm10))
        curs.execute("INSERT INTO temperatures values(?,?,?)", (timestamp, sensorID, temp ))
        curs.execute("INSERT INTO co values(?,?,?)", (timestamp, sensorID, co ))
        curs.execute("INSERT INTO pm25 values(?,?,?)", (timestamp, sensorID, pm25 ))
        curs.execute("INSERT INTO pm10 values(?,?,?)", (timestamp, sensorID, pm10 ))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

#main
    def main():
        while True:
            temp = gettemp()
            pm25 = getpm25()
            pm10 = getpm10()
            co = getco()
            logdata(temp, co, pm25, pm10)
            time.sleep(refresh)

#-----execute program... gooo!
main()
```

But, at every loop, the same timestamp from the first run is outputted:

[image: terminal outputs showing same timestamp after 3 loops]

How can this be?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `timestamp` is created only once. You need to get current time every time your want to print it. You can put your `t=...` and `timestamp=...` in a function e.g. called `get_current_time()` and then use `print(get_current_time())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You run these lines at the start of your code:

```
t = time.localtime()
timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', t)
```

These only run once (not in a loop) and the timestamp in them never changes. If you want to update the timestamp you should make those lines part of your loop, or better yet, use a function:

```
def get_timestamp():
    t = time.localtime()
    return time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', t)
```

And replace every time you try to use `timestamp` with `get_timestamp()`

Answer (score 1):

`timestamp` is used in several method so define it as a `global` variable in the `main` method to be able to update its value and Reset `timestamp` inside the while loop in each iteration:

```
def main():
    global timestamp 
    while True:
       timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime())
       temp = gettemp()
       pm25 = getpm25()
       pm10 = getpm10()
       ...
       ...
```

But keep the first lines at the top of the file to keep `timestamp`a global variable:

```
sensorID = "1"
dbname = 'sensorsData.db'

# temestamp should stay a global variable
timestamp = None
```

Comment: `timestamp` is used in several method so define it as a global variable in the `main` so you can update it's value without errors .

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess the problem is that you would need to call the used function

```
timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', t)
```

every time the outer function is called, but you just save the value of this specific point in time and print it repeatedly.

```
def gettemp():
    temp = subprocess.check_output("sudo python /home/pi/AIRQMONITOR/temp.py", shell=True)
    print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', t) )
    return(temp)
```

This should work out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a function to calculate time stamp, let's say `get_timestamp()` :

```
def get_timestamp():
    t = time.localtime()
    return time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', t)
```

after that you need to call get_timestamp in your `main` function :

```
def main():
    while True:
        temp = gettemp()
        pm25 = getpm25()
        pm10 = getpm10()
        co = getco()
        timestamp = get_timestamp()
        logdata(temp, co, pm25, pm10,timestamp)
        time.sleep(refresh)
```

all you need now is to change the `logdata` so that it takes timestamp as input :

```
def logdata(temp,co,pm25,pm10,timestamp):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    curs=conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("INSERT INTO sensors values(?,?,?,?,?)", (timestamp, temp, co, pm25, pm10))
    curs.execute("INSERT INTO temperatures values(?,?,?)", (timestamp, sensorID, temp ))
    curs.execute("INSERT INTO co values(?,?,?)", (timestamp, sensorID, co ))
    curs.execute("INSERT INTO pm25 values(?,?,?)", (timestamp, sensorID, pm25 ))
    curs.execute("INSERT INTO pm10 values(?,?,?)", (timestamp, sensorID, pm10 ))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

and remove the following lines from your code :

```
t = time.localtime()
timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', t)
```